# Low space on /boot

Tags: boot

When I boot up I get the message that the /boot is low on space.

I have been reading various responses but when I type the command 'dpkg -l | grep linux-image-' it tells me that the "-1" is not recognised.

Is there an updated version of Ubuntu Tweak? I have Ubuntu 15.04.

I could resize the /boot partition with Gparted but I am new to ubuntu and uncertain about doing that.

```
sudo dpkg -1 linux-image-* | grep ^ii 
[sudo] password for david: 
dpkg: error: unknown option -1 
Type dpkg --help for help about installing and uninstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management; 
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values; 
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options; 
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
```

Comment: "-1" may be typo,...please copy paste command,and comment ,if any change=)

Comment: dpkg -1 | grep linux-image-

Comment: that is not 1 , see my answer =)

Comment: please observe my screenshot in answer

Answer (score 1):

From your comment ,you are using **1** instead of *l*
 the correct command is:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-
```

---

Sample Output:

```
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic                         3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic                         3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic                   3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic                   3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic                        3.16.0.50.41                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

---

Apart from that  typo, remaining question is duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Also I didn't find any Ubuntu tweak for vivid ,refer [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/ubuntu-tweak)

---

I am adding this screenshot to show the difference:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Yes I was using the correct command (several times). The response I get is that -1 is not recognised.

Comment: please , just copy the command in my answer and paste in your terminal..@DavidAshton

Comment: this is what I get when I type the command :david@david-ProBook-650-G1:~$ sudo dpkg -1 linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
[sudo] password for david: 
dpkg: error: unknown option -1

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and uninstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Comment: david still I see 1 not l in lion...please copy command in my  answer...@DavidAshton

Comment: @DavidAshton please accept it as answer if it  solved your  problem=)

Answer (score 0):

You might free the /boot by removing old kernel and initrd image.

Example:

```
root@Lenovo-G40:/boot# uname -a
Linux Lenovo-G40 3.19.0-30-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 20:58:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From above command i'm running kernel `3.19.0-30-generic`.

Now go to `/boot` and do `ls`.

```
root@Lenovo-G40:/boot# ls
abi-3.19.0-15-generic     grub                          memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
abi-3.19.0-30-generic     initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin      vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic.efi.signed
config-3.19.0-15-generic  initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic  System.map-3.19.0-15-generic
config-3.19.0-30-generic  lost+found                    System.map-3.19.0-30-generic
efi                       memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic
```

Now we will remove old kernel and initrd (also all files associated to that version 3.19.0-15).`rm -rf initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic abi-3.19.0-15-generic config-3.19.0-15-generic System.map-3.19.0-15-generic vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic`.

Lastly, update grub to make sure the grub bootloader entry updated via `update-grub`.

To extend the filesystem for boot, we need extra effort and very risky. Since `/boot` are located infront of the disk sector. Assuming you still have free space on your disk, you need to move the disk layout to get some space for `/boot`.

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   1550335    499712  244M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1550336 976771071 975220736  465G Linux LVM
```

From above you can see the end sector of `/dev/sda2` (which `/boot` reside) 1550335 and start sector of `/dev/sda3` (in this case `/root`) 1550336 are continuous.

To extend boot, you need to make some space between /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3. Gparted can help you archive this, but the filesystem involve need to be offline and there must be of course a free space on the disk.